# C# getting the filename of a file you open in the openfiledialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

Is there a way to get the file name of a file you open using the openfiledialog in C#? I need this because, the user is going to open an image file, but then the image file is added to a listbox(using its filename), then can be selected for display in a picturebox. Having trouble finding a solution for this.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`OpenFileDialog.FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx):

```
if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    InsertIntoList(openFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `openfiledialog.FileName` property?

Answer (score 0):

use `openFileDialog.SafeFileName` to get just the name of the file

`openFileDialog.FileName` returns the full path to the file